# MySQL Query, calculating available funds

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to retrieve an id of an ad, if the user has enough funds in his/her account to finance the cost of displaying the ad. I'm getting very lost though,

Mysql Schema:

```
campaign_deposit:
c_id (campaign id), btc (amount deposited)...

ad_view:
a_id (ad id), btc (cost of impression)...

ad:
id (ad id), uv (cost of impression)...
```

The MySQL error:

```
Unknown column 'ad.c_id' in 'where clause'
```

-Query:

```
SELECT id FROM 
( 
SELECT *, 
(
    SELECT SUM(btc) as btc FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT `btc` FROM ad_view WHERE a_id IN 
        (
            SELECT id FROM ad WHERE c_id = ad.c_id
        ) OR ad_space_id IN 
        (
            SELECT id FROM ad WHERE c_id = ad.c_id
        ) 
        UNION ALL SELECT (`btc` * -1) AS `deposit` FROM 
        campaign_deposit WHERE c_id=ad.c_id GROUP BY c_id 
    ) AS Total
) AS deposit FROM ad
) AS ad 
WHERE uv >= 0 AND click >= 0 AND uv < deposit AND click < deposit AND deleted=0 AND c_id IN 
(
    SELECT id FROM campaign WHERE publisher = 0 AND deleted=0
) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please include your database schema.  The query is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

We need to see your database schema in order to understand whether these queries are sensible or not. What columns are on the `ad` table?

If you're getting lost when writing MySQL queries, to me that's a sign that you need to break your queries down into simpler ones.

First of all, get familiar with mysql's `JOIN` syntax; it lets you do many of the things you're doing with nested queries, but structures them in a way that's easier to read and easier to think through.

Secondly and more importantly, I don't think you should be putting complex MySQL queries into production code if you're not absolutely confident in what they do and how they'll work. You're working in PHP, so it should be easy to run one query at a time, gather the results in variables, and use those variables in subsequent queries. That way you're not left troubleshooting one huge monolithic query; instead you can troubleshoot `SELECT id FROM ad WHERE c_id = ad.c_id` in isolation, which will be much easier to find a fix for (or get answers for here on SO).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ideally I would break it down into smaller queries.
But I need to calculate the amount deposited for each campaign, of which there could be hundreds. In the end it only selects one ad of the campaign which has enough deposited. Wouldn't it be better to try and do this all in a mysql query?

Comment: OK, yes I see what you're trying to do. But if it's causing you enough grief / confusion that you need to write on SO for help figuring out what you're doing, I think you're better off running multiple queries, each of which is more easily understandable. As a rule, I optimize for the developer first and for the computer second; remember the rule "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". If you haven't tried this query a different way and seen *definitive* proof that you need to maximize efficiency, then the only thing you know for sure is that you're making more work for yourself.

Comment: "I optimize for the developer first and for the computer second" :) I will heed this advice. Have actually got it working, will remove question when I can, thanks a lot!